# Execute the shell script that is in the current directory, not the one in $PATH

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have defined the path in .bash_profile file for /usr/share/totalscripts as:

```
PATH="${PATH}:/usr/share/totalscripts"
export PATH
```

Where all my shell scripts programs are present - /usr/share/totalscripts

Specifically, I need to execute the scripts in the current directory, not the one available in my $PATH environment variable.  That is, executing a specific script rather than any script that matches that is found in the PATH.

For example, it might make sense to not call `script1.sh` (which will execute against any script1.sh found in the PATH), but instead call `./script1.sh` (which will only execute the script that is found in the local directory).

This because I have the same script under `/usr/share/totalscripts/script1.sh` and `/home/script1.sh` (same names)

Comment: The scripts you execute must change the directory themselfs before proceeded with what they are supposted to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working in a script, then you can define your environment variables at the start of it, like:

```
MY_VAR="/my/path/to/scripts"
```

And then call your script from within that script using:

```
${MY_VAR}/my_script.sh
```

Kind of the same as running the script using its full path.

I hope this helps!

---

Edit 1: - If you want to run a specific script as you mentioned in the comments, under a specific directory, you can try changing directories to the one that contains the file, and then running the script like `./script1.sh`.

```
cd /path/containing/your/scripts/
./script1.sh
```

---

Edit 2: - Maybe you can create a wrapper for your `script1.sh`, placing the following if-block in there to check if the script is under the current directory or not.

```
if [ -e script1.sh ]; then
    ./script1.sh     # runs the script under your current directory
else
    script1.sh       # runs the script searching for it in $PATH first
fi
```

Comment: I have added PATH for /usr/share/totalscripts in .bash_profile file....I see here that scripts names under /usr/share/totalscripts are getting executed from different paths as the scripts names are same and they are using the path from .bash_profile. so here what I want is I should able run scripts under using scripts names when I am location /usr/share/totalscripts and apart this /usr/share/totalscripts location and scriopts should only get execute by using bash script1.sh or ./script1.sh

Comment: I have updated the question and I think it will be clear now.

Comment: @user2783146 - In your script, just change directory (`cd`) first, just before running the script like `./script1.sh`.  I'm sure that should work.  I have edited my answer as well.

Comment: yes that works at any location as it is in path.......and I need it should only from from /usr/share/totalscripts by using name of script as script1.sh  and in other  location like /home it should only execute when you run ./script1.sh and it should not pick file from path. I mean from /home just executing by file name should not work.

Comment: @user2783146 - Sounds like you may want to take off the script's location from your $PATH variable, and then just use the `cd` and run trick to call your scripts.

Comment: sorry but here what is happening is I have declared a path in .bash_profile for /usr/share/totalscripts and it contains script1.sh and same file in at /home directory. cd /home and when try to run ./script1.sh it is  picking up from path and trying to run instead it should run from current directory

Comment: thanks for your patience for answering I really appreciate it jim

Comment: @user2783146 - you're welcome :)  Please take a look at the second edit in my answer.

Comment: @user2783146: when you execute `./script1.sh` or any name with a slash in it, the setting of `$PATH` is irrelevant; the shell does not even look at `$PATH`. It simply treats the name as a file name -- as an absolute name if it starts with `/` and as a relative name (meaning relative to the current directory) if it does not.  If you think that's incorrect, provide a counter-example (which will be a little tricky to set up, but can be done with a little care).  A non-standard shell might try to be clever about something, but you'd identify the shell if that was the case.

Comment: when I run scripts with just name script1.sh it picks the $PATH and execute and when run same script from current directory where scripts exists like ./script1.sh it again picks up $PATH and executes. this is the problem I was facing.

Comment: when I execute the scripts form current directory using ./script1.sh it should execute from current directory irrespective of $PATH. But the thing is it always picks files from $PATH (eg: either ./script1.sh or script1.sh)